# Comparing 2 Pivot Tables using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, comparison, pivot-table

I have 2 PivotTable in the same workbook. I am now trying to compare the 2 tables, to find if the row label for each in PivotTable A, is found in PivotTable B. If it exists in both, then i would like to compare the values in the same rows to see if they matched. Results and remarks will be shown in a new worksheet of the same book. Here is an example of what i am trying to accomplish. I dont know if there are any feasible way, right now i am trying to use 2 for loops, to loop in both pivottables. But i am not sure on how to get the values of the cells of the rows that exists

**Sheet1**

PivotTable A

[image]

**Sheet2**

PivotTable B

[image]

Output Sheet3

[image]

This is a snip of what im trying to do:

```
    Set brmSheet = Worksheets("PivotA")
    Set bscsSheet = Worksheets("PivotB")
    ' Print all the row labels
    Set pt = brmSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set pt2 = bscsSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    
    'Debug.Print pt.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 1 + 1 To pt.RowRange.Count - 1
        For j = 1 + 1 To pt2.RowRange.Count - 1
            If pt.RowRange.Cells(i).Value = pt2.RowRange.Cells(j).Value Then
                Debug.Print "Found " & pt.RowRange.Cells(i).Row & " : " & pt.RowRange.Cells(i).Value
            End If
            
        Next j
        
        'Debug.Print pt.RowRange.Cells(i).Row & ": " & pt.RowRange.Cells(i).Value
    Next i
```

Comment: I try to do this, but i wont work















Set pt = brmSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set pt2 = bscsSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    
    'Debug.Print pt.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 1 + 1 To pt.RowRange.Count - 1
        Debug.Print pt.RowRange(i)
    Next i

error at pt.RowRange(i)

Answer (score 0):

I do it so - create 2 arrays, read data from each pivot to array and compare. You know the pivot range - so pivots are not dynamical ranges? it's easy.

```
Dim a(),b(),count1 as Long,count2 as Long
count1=0'dimensiom of the first array
Do While Cells(count1+1,1)<>0if pivot b starts in 1 column
count1=count1+1
Loop
count2=0'dimensiom of the second array
Do While Cells(count2+1,6)<>0'if pivot b starts in 6 column
count2=count2+1
Loop
'filling the arrays 
ReDim a(count1,4)
Redim b(count2,4)
For i=2 to count1
For j=2 to 4
a(j,i)=cells(i,j)
Next j
Next i
ReDim a(count1,4)
Redim b(count2,4)

For i=2 to count2
For j=2 to 4
b(j,i)=cells(i,j+5)
Next j
Next i
'then comparing arrays
For i=1 to count1
For j=1 to count2
If a(3,i)=j(3,j) Then 'your code
.....
Next j
Next i
```

Comment: the pivots are dynamic range. So pivot are longer list than some other pivots. But i wasnt sure how to create a pivottable with dynamic range. my code right now is  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "BRM Data!R2C1:R32330C39", Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        sheetName & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=7

Comment: as you have noticed, first code is counting the current length of pivot tables 'Dim a(),b(),count1 as Long,count2 as Long
count1=0'dimensiom of the first array
Do While Cells(count1+1,1)<>0if pivot b starts in 1 column
count1=count1+1
Loop
count2=0'dimensiom of the second array
Do While Cells(count2+1,6)<>0'if pivot b starts in 6 column
count2=count2+1
Loop'

Comment: TableDestination:= _ sheetName & "!R3C1  start point of pivot is not dynamic - you know what range pivot starts, you know the number of pivot tables columns, and count the length of each pivot by the first pivot column - then collect the data into arrays and compare

Comment: So based on the examples that u gave, i should save all the rows, columns datas into an array for each pivot. and then compare them ?

Comment: yea i know its not dynamic. not sure how to create a pivottable with dynamic # of rows/columns